# Shopware 5 - 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type

Tags: authentication, zend-framework, shopware, zend-mail, shopware5

I have a problem with sending mails through Shopware5.
Here is the error I get:

> 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type

And here is the whole log:

```
^ array:13 [▼
  0 => "220 SRV02EX16.private.domain.de Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 12 Jul 2023 15:33:19 +0200
"
  1 => "EHLO mx02.domain.de
"
  2 => "250-SRV02EX16.private.domain.de Hello [IPAddress]
"
  3 => "250-SIZE 37748736
"
  4 => "250-PIPELINING
"
  5 => "250-DSN
"
  6 => "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
"
  7 => "250-STARTTLS
"
  8 => "250-8BITMIME
"
  9 => "250-BINARYMIME
"
  10 => "250 CHUNKING
"
  11 => "AUTH LOGIN
"
  12 => "504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type
"
]
```

I tried it through ssh and the openssl command… and **the mail will be sent**:

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect mx02.domain.de:25 -starttls smtp
EHLO mx02.domain.de
AUTH LOGIN
username
passwrod
MAIL FROM: im-shop@domain.de
rcpt to: mymail
DATA
subject: Your Subject
from: im-shop@domain.de
to: mymail
.
QUIT
```

So Auth Login must be recognized.
Any ideas what the problem is?

Thanks!

Comment: how is the mailer configured in Shopware? is this on every mail, Shopware tries to send or only specific ones?